# How to find "only" IP addresses in a Local Area Network

Tags: networking, lan, sharing, smb

```
sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet
```

I know the above command works fine but it outputs everything like MAC address etc, etc.
But I need to find only IP addresses. Is it possible ?

Comment: Use grep to filter your output (or perl or awk .... )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just used `awk`,`tail` and `head` to achieve what you want:

```
sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet| awk '{print $1}'|tail -n +3|head -n -2
```

this gives the output as

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.3
```

as I have only these two in my Lan.

Here `awk '{print $1}'` prints the ip address which is situated in the first column.
`tail` and `head` removes unnecessary stuff like the header and just shows the ip addresses.

Answer (score 9):

I would do this using just `grep`:

```
$ sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet | grep -oP '^[\d.]+'
192.168.0.1 
192.168.0.2 
192.168.0.3 
192.168.0.10    
192.168.0.23    
192.168.0.72    
192.168.27.1    
192.168.27.14
192.168.27.30
```

**Explanation:**

The `-P` tells `grep` to use Perl Compatible Regular Expressions, where `\d` matches any number. The `-o` means "print only the matching part of the line". The regular expression I used means match the longest string (that's what the `+` means)  of consecutive numbers (`\d`) or dots (`.`) that are at the beginning of the line (`^`).

Comment: `sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet | grep -oP '^[\d]+[.]+[\d.]+'` is more accurate, as the above also includes regular numbers at the start of sentence, which `arp-scan` does on my linux.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Here is a one liner to get the IP address using the ifconfig command:</strike>

```
~$ ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'
192.168.1.10
```

Does that do what you wanted?  Or did you need the arp-scan command?

I re-read and see I missed the point of the question. `arp-scan` shows the local IP addresses for the network and I only showed the IP of the machine with `ifconfig`. Below is a version of the above terdon solution only not using the PCRE library. Ubuntu had an issue with pcre and grep when I tried it.

```
$ sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet | grep -o ^[0-9.]*
```

Comment: You are correct.  I see what he was asking now.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Have an upvote. What was the problem on Ubuntu? I tested mine on Debian so there may well be a difference.

Comment: I tried the -P and didn't get the pcre support working for me. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.3 and 12.10. Tried `pcregrep` as well and it wasn't happy. I'm digging some more on my setup because I like Perl syntax better for grep. Perl was the first regex I used so I have a soft spot for it.

Comment: I'm using this to scan my local network and finding some interesting systems I hadn't documented. Glad this question came up.

Comment: I just tried on my 13.10 VM and it worked fine: `echo "1.2.3.44.5 ljasd asdlnasd " | grep -Po '[\d.]+'`. Make sure you quote the pattern: `'[\d.]+'`. And of course you like PCREs, they're by far the best regex flavor around! :)

Comment: By the way, for this kind of more obscure issue you might have better luck asking on [unix.se] where there are more hardcore *nix as opposed to only Ubuntu geeks.

Comment: The backslash is missing on your `\d` above in the code section. I tried several variations but never hit all of them at once. It also needs the single quotes or failed for me.

Comment: Argh! Sorry, that was a typo. Yes the single quotes are needed, otherwise `grep` will treat it as a string. And of course the `\d` is needed, thanks for pointing it out. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

another option to simplify @Stormvirux answer is to use the **--quiet** or **-q** and **--plain** or **-x** arguments provided with **arp-scan** instead of piping to **head** and **tail** commands the final command will be simpler as it will pipe only to **awk** :

```
arp-scan -qx --localnet | awk '{print $1}'
```

and here is a much detailed explanation from **arp-scan --help** :

```
--quiet or -q       Only display minimal output. No protocol decoding.
            If this option is specified, then only the IP address
            and MAC address are displayed for each responding host.
            No protocol decoding is performed and the OUI mapping
            files are not used.

--plain or -x       Display plain output showing only responding hosts.
            This option suppresses the printing of the header and
            footer text, and only displays one line for each
            responding host. Useful if the output will be
            parsed by a script.
```